# Loadable kernel module not compiles correctly on different computers

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module

I'm trying to make loadable kernel module for ARM achitecture. Just for example I'm made simple hello.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}
module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

And created Makefile

```
obj-m := hello.o

PWD := $(shell pwd)

ARCH=arm
CROSS_COMPILE_LINARO=/home/cooperok/mk908/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.01-20130125_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
KERNEL_ROCKCHIP=/home/cooperok/mk908/kernel/

default:
    make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE_LINARO) -C $(KERNEL_ROCKCHIP) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE_LINARO) -C $(KERNEL_ROCKCHIP) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Cross compiler and kernel sources are the same on both computers. When I'm running make on first machine compiled hello.ko file is successfully installed with insmod command, but when I'm compiling module on second machine and trying to install that module I'm getting error "***insmod: error inserting 'hello.ko': -1 Invalid module format***"

As I understand module is compiling with crosscompiler which I'm specified in CROSS_COMPILE (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc and others) and only it will make module without any specific libraries installed on computers, is it?

First computer have 64bit OS (Ubuntu 12.04), and second 32bit OS (Linux Mint 12), this is main difference, so make util is different. But is it realy main reason why module correctly compiling only on 64bit OS? If so is it problem in make, or it's really deals with different libraries?

Comment: Does the system log [give any more hints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341701/cross-compiling-a-kernel-module-invalid-module-format?rq=1)?

Comment: I'll be able to check it only in monday, but as I remember dmesg didn't show any message about error.

Comment: Oops. There was error.    
[ 1405.917668] hello: version magic '3.0.36 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7 ' should be '3.0.36+ SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7 '

Comment: Ah, so the sources aren't quite the same, hence the mismatch - you'll have to track down why the "+" version has (or thinks it has) additional patches on top of 3.0.36.